# spreading props in makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

With material-ui's [makeStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/), is there an option to spread props in an object applying all the styles?

I.e.:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme) => ({
    card: {
      ...props # <- props has stuff like backgroundColor, fontSize etc.
    },
    thisWorks: {
      backgroundColor: (props) => props.backgroundColor,
      fontSize: (props) => props.fontSize,
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Have a look at the documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props).

You can pass props to your `useStyles` hook.

Since you get the `props` as params of your declared functions inside your `makeStyles`, you have to use functions. But this does not prevent you from using the spread operator.

Just keep in mind that you need to return an object at the end

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  // use the spread operator
  card: (props) => ({
    // dynamic styles from props
    ...props,
    // static styles
    border: "1px solid red"
  }),

  // more explicit way if you need just specific props
  card2: (props) => {
    const { backgroundColor, color } = props;
    return {
      backgroundColor,
      color
    };
  }
}));
...

const MyComponent = () => {

  const myProps = {
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    fontSize: "32px",
  };

  const classes = useStyles(myProps)

  return (<div className={classes.card}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

### Here is a live example:

[image: Edit spreading-props-in-makestyles]